# Inserting an image into HTML <span class="

Tags: html, css, image

I am attempting to insert an image into an HTML script? Example:  How do I choose the image that is utilized where the parentheses are? Thank you!

Comment: span class="_________"/span How do I choose the image that is utilized where the parentheses are?

Comment: Which HTML script? Which image? What parentheses??

Answer (score 4):

`class=""` is not used to insert images. It's a class name. Therefore:
if you're interested in inserting an image using `class` than probably it's about a `backgroud-image`:

HTML

```
<span class="someClassName"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.someClassName{
   display: inline-block;
   width:   100px;
   height:  100px;
   background-image: url("pathtoimage.jpg");
}
```

otherwise you need an `<img src="pathtoimage.jpg" alt="">` HTML tag inside your SPAN element